# Listing/1 with char codes displayed as characters and not codes?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

Using SWI-Prolog

Version:

```
?- current_prolog_flag(windows,Value).
Value = true.

?- current_prolog_flag(version,Value).
Value = 80000.
```

For a simple DCG

```
constant_value --> "ID".
```

[listing/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=listing/1) outputs

```
?- listing(constant_value).

constant_value([73, 68|A], A).
```

However in my notes I have it as

```
?- listing(constant_value).

constant_value(['I', 'D'|A], A).
```

but I don't know what I did to have the character codes appear as characters.

I tried the SWI-Prolog flag [double_quotes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags#flag:double_quotes) with various values (chars, codes, string) but can't reproduce the desired output.

How are listing/1 of a DCG created where the character codes are displayed as characters?

Comment: Of interest: [Prolog DCG set_prolog_flag double_quotes source code directive location matters; documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45390050/1243762)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264699/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-prolog/8269897#8269897).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you probably had *double_quotes* flag in `codes` when constant_value was compiled. The value of this flag won't affect clauses already stored in the database.

```
constant_value1 --> "ID".
:-set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
constant_value2 --> "ID".

?- listing(constant_value1).
constant_value1([73, 68|A], A).
?- listing(constant_value2).
constant_value2(['I', 'D'|A], A).
```

---

Edit by Guy Coder

Since I use the Q&A at SO as a personal notebook with my own Q&A, I tend to look at the accepted answer for the details; I am adding them here for everyone's benefit.

As this answer correctly states, the problem was caused by the fact that originally in the source code, which was a module stored as a file, I had the statement

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).
```

before the code

```
constant_value --> "ID".
```

then in the REPL

```
?- consult('C:/dcg_examples.pl').  

?- listing(constant_value).
constant_value(['I', 'D'|A], A).

true.
```

and to use this

```
?- phrase(constant_value,"ID").
true.
```

Latter in the source code I changed the value for `double_quotes`

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,codes).
```

notice the change from `chars` to `codes`

Restarting the REPL and doing the same

```
?- consult('C:/dcg_examples.pl').  

?- listing(constant_value).
constant_value([73, 68|A], A).

true.

?- phrase(constant_value,"ID").
true.
```

gave the different result for listing/1.

However in the REPL using

```
set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,<VALUE>).
```

had no effect on the result of listing/1.

<[VALUE](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags#flag:double_quotes)> can be one of `string`, `chars`, `codes`, `traditional`, or `atom`.

The key point to note here is that listing/1 uses consulted/compiled/stored code. So the value of `double_quotes` at the time of consulting/compiling/storing is what listing/1 uses. Any changes to `double_quotes` after that in the REPL will not change the consulted/compiled/stored code and thus the result of listing/1.

To effect a change you have to add

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,<VALUE>).
```

in your source code before the predicate then [consult/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=consult/1) to load it and then listing/1.

The meaning of consulted/compiled/stored does not imply that these are three separate actions performed in a sequence, here they define when the source code is put into the database for use by listing/1.

Comment: I was writing an answer after I figured it out. Your answer is correct, but I don't think it has enough detail for others that read this in the future. Care if I accept this answer and then modify it with details?

Comment: @GuyCoder: I'd say you do whatever benefits others the most in the future, including adding and accepting your own answer if you think that would be better (I've seen you writing very detailed posts here ;)